# What is the easiest Server-Side Javascript to learn?

Tags: serverside-javascript

I'm a CSS, JS, and jQuery front end developer.  I have been hearing a lot about server-side javascript.  However, there is not a lot of information for newcomers to SSJS.

What is the easiest Server-Side Javascript to get my feet wet?

My criteria for "easy":

1. simple to install (prefer one that runs on many servers, but not a deal killer just for learning)
2. well documented
3. easiest to wrap brain around

Thanks All!

Answer (score 2):

The most used server-side JavaScript approach today is node.js. If you're on Linux, it's a pretty straightforward installation, but I didn't get it working on Windows though. Most servers run Unix systems, so that isn't such a problem though.

Note that other people usually get it working on Windows, so give it a try.

Comment: Since they now offer a 5MB single .exe file it's possible to seamlessly work with Node on Windows, although it's still experimental.

Comment: Really?! That's awesome! I went trough a hell of a trouble trying to set it up, and it didn't work at all! I'll check it out later.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find something here http://groups.google.com/group/commonjs

Answer (score 1):

I would give [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) a go. IMO it fulfills all your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I agree node.js would be quite easier and well-versed.